# How to display an image in a specific tkinter window using PhotoImage?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, project, photoimage

I have two running tkinter windows but I want only one specific window to display the image but I am not able to achieve this. I tried to specify the master in the Label statement but python shows an error which says "image pyimage1 doesn't exist"
Please help

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

a=tk.Tk()
a.geometry('800x500+275+100')
a.title('HOME PAGE')

c=tk.Tk()
c.geometry('800x500+275+100')
c.title('PROFILE')

load=Image.open('untitled.png')
render=ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)
img=tk.Label(c,image=render)
img.pack()

a.mainloop()
c.mainloop()
```

Comment: You should use `Toplevel()` for `c`: `c = tk.Toplevel()`.  And remove `c.mainloop()` as well.

Comment: See [Why are multiple instances of Tk discouraged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48045401/why-are-multiple-instances-of-tk-discouraged)

Comment: Apart from all this, if you still wish to keep two instance of `Tk()` then change your `render` to `render=ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=load,master=c)`, but still more changes might be needed later on to make the whole app work properly

Comment: oh thanks @acw1668 it works now

Comment: @CoolCloud I tried, it's working thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a second screen use `tk.Toplevel` and remove `c.mainloop`

```
a=tk.Tk()
a.geometry('800x500+275+100')
a.title('HOME PAGE')

c=tk.Toplevel()
c.geometry('800x500+275+100')
c.title('PROFILE')

load=Image.open('untitled.png')
render=ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)
img=tk.Label(c,image=render)
img.pack()

a.mainloop()
```

Comment: no problem, you can accept my answer by giving it a tick